# How to use hardware virtualization?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have used hardware assisted virtualization in over a year now.
The difference in performance is huge. But last week is stop working.
This is critical as I spend most of my workday in VmWare Workstation.

I got a message

*VMware Workstation does not support nested virtualization on this host.
Module 'MonitorMode' power on failed.
Failed to start the virtual machine.*

If I uncheck checkbox Settings/Processors/Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI
the VM starts fine but with slower performance.

So something must have changed!
I suspect a Windows update.

**Version**: VmWare WorkStation Pro 15.5.7 Build-17171714

**Host**: Windows 10 Enterprise 20H2  64-bit

**Guest**: Windows 10 Pro 20H2   64-bit

CPU is Intel Core I7 9th generation with 32 GB RAM.

What are my options ?

- First I try to contact VmWare support. But it was incredible complicated, Maybe I have to buy support ?
- Upgrade to latest VmWare 16.1 ? I can do that if I am sure it helps.
- I suspect Hyper-V is still active and cause a conflict with VmWare hypervisor. But how do I turn off Hyper-V apart from the obvious in "Turn Windows features off and on" ?

I asked the same question in VmWare forum without response. I really need a fix for this!

Comment: Please launch `msinfo32` and take a look at the bottom of the summary. Does it say “A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.”? VMware Workstation is compatible with Hyper-V. Maybe try updating. // Do you truly need _nested virtualization_? Because that’s what the option you mention enables. Even when disabled you’re still using hardware-assisted virtualization.

Comment: To disable Hyper-V use the command `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` and reboot. However, the latest WorkStation version 16.1.2 is supposedly compatible with it, so it's not supposed to be necessary.

Comment: `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` was already tried

Comment: msInfo bottom display have this:

**A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.**

So you mean to make VMware be able to use hardware virtualization it needs to say something like "A hypervisor has not been detected" ?